# Arithmetic average of a series of numbers

Tags: java

The statement says:

> Successive integers read from the keyboard. When you read a -1, the 
>   program must indicate how many numbers between 1 and 100 we read and
>   what  is their arithmetic mean (MediaNum.java).

I push this code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class MediaNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number, sum=0, medium;
        int counter=0;
        System.out.println("When you want to finish enter '-1'.");
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers:");
        number = entrada.nextDouble();
        while (number != -1){
            sum = sum + number;
            counter++;
            number = entrada.nextDouble();
        }
        if (number == -1){
            counter++;
            System.out.println("counter");
        }
        if (number == -1 && number < 101){
            medium = sum/counter;
            System.out.println("The medium of the numbers entered is: "+medium);
        }
    }   
}
```

The part of the medium and the part when I put -1 the counter finishes is correct but the error is when i put a number above 100 the counter counts this number and the medium will be incorrect.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Will error if the first number is -1.  You have to check inside your loop if its over 100 or else you're going to add it when its over 100. Also, after your loop you dont have to recheck if number == -1

Comment: Your existing `if` tests are useless because they will always be true--you can't get to those lines unless `number == -1`. The last one is also a bit redundant regardless of the value of `number` because if `number == -1` then `number < 101` will also be true (and if it is not, then `number < 100` will not even be evaluated due to how `&&` works).

Comment: How can i only count the numbers between 1 and 100

Comment: You have a loop in which you process each number that the user inputs.  If you want to test each number to see if it's between 1 and 100, you have to put the test **inside** the loop.  If you put it outside the loop, you won't be able to look at every input number.

Comment: Thanks you all I solucionate the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count the number if it meets the criteria:

```
while (number != -1){
    if(number >= 1 && number <= 100) {
        sum += number;
        counter++;
    }
    number = entrada.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: Yeah i dont realize of this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem

```
  while (number != -1){
            sum = sum + number;
            counter++;
            number = entrada.nextDouble();
        }
```

You are adding every number, you only want those < 100

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import java.util.*;


public class MediaNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        double number=0, sum=0, medium=0;
        int counter=0;
        System.out.println("When you want to finish enter '-1'.");
        while(number!=-1){
            System.out.println("Enter the numbers:");
            number = entrada.nextDouble();
            if((number>100 || number<1)&&number!=-1){
                continue;
            }
            if(number==-1){
                break;
            }
            sum += number;
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("counter :" +counter);
        if(counter!=0){
            medium = sum/counter;
        }
        System.out.println("The medium of the numbers entered is: "+medium);
    }
}
```

Comment: I push this code but there is an error because when i put a number abobe 100, the counter ends and i dont want this because i only want to finish when i push -1

Comment: but you would count only the numbers between 1 and 100 ?

Comment: Ok error fixed now the program will not stop until you enter -1

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one.It works.I did it using recursive function.Add comments if it works.

```
import java.util.*;
class AM{
    double s=0;int co=0;
    double p;
    public void show(){

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number:-");
        p=sc.nextDouble();
        if(p!=-1&&p<=100){
            s+=p;
            co++;
            show();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The average is:-"+(s/co));
            System.out.println(co+" "+"numbers were entered.");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my code and reminding me that it is always good to follow the convention :-)